# jQuery button doesn't respond in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a three-step form. After every step, the user needs to click the `Next button`. `Next button` checks if the user has fulfilled the inputs.

**If no:** Gives error.

**If yes:** Goes to next step.

My problem is that the `Next button` doesn't respond at all in Safari and IE. I highly believe this is all about my JavaScript code. (But I'm not sure.)

**JavaScript**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        // Custom method to validate username
        $.validator.addMethod("usernameRegex", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i.test(value);
        }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers");

        $(".next").click(function(){
            var form = $("#myform");
            form.validate({
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                },
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        usernameRegex: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                    },
                    password : {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: '#password',
                    },
                    company:{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    url:{
                        required: true,
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                    },

                },
                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Username required",
                    },
                    password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                        equalTo: "Password don't match",
                    },
                    name: {
                        required: "Name required",
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Email required",
                    },
                }
            });
            if (form.valid() === true){
                if ($('#account_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#account_information');
                    next_fs = $('#company_information');
                }else if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#company_information');
                    next_fs = $('#personal_information');
                }

                next_fs.show(); 
                current_fs.hide();
            }
        });

        $('#previous').click(function(){
            if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                current_fs = $('#company_information');
                next_fs = $('#account_information');
            }else if ($('#personal_information').is(":visible")){
                current_fs = $('#personal_information');
                next_fs = $('#company_information');
            }
            next_fs.show(); 
            current_fs.hide();
        });

    });
```

**JsFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/r6sztnsh/1/

Comment: The fiddle works for me in Safari and IE. I click on Next and it gives validation errors for all the fields.

Comment: Things are somehow working on JsFiddle all the time. Same code here, and you will see it's not working. [link](http://areafordemos.net63.net/ip/validate.html)

Comment: Script is working well on safari and IE, can you specify the version of browsers.

Comment: Script might be working on jsFidle but it doesn't work on webpage itself. I am checking on IE 11 and iOS 8's mobile safari browser. [here](http://areafordemos.net63.net/ip/validate.html) and it doesn't respond when I click "Next"